# Stack: docker + nginx + postgres + django data lost

Tags: django, database, postgresql, docker

I have several Digital Ocean droplets (5$) hosting docker with django and postgres (image mdillon/postgis) but since 2 weeks ago I have lost data in 7 of them randomly. In all of these droplets Postgres database is located in a volume but even so it lost all the django tables and return to default status. Some of these droplet had been working for months and others just days. All of them have the same docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    build: './docks/nginx/.'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - letsencrypt_certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - letsencrypt_www:/var/www/letsencrypt
    volumes_from:
      - web:ro
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build: './sources/.'
    image: 'websource'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:8000:8000'
    env_file: '.env'
    command: '/venv/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application -k gevent -w 3 -b :8000 --worker-connections=1000 --reload --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance --log-level=debug --access-logfile=- --log-file=-'
    volumes:
      - 'cachedata:/cache'
      - 'mediadata:/media'
      - 'staticdata:/static'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  celery_worker:
    image: 'websource'
    env_file: '.env'
    command: 'python -m celery -A project worker -l debug'
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web

  celery_beat:
    container_name: 'celery_beat'
    image: 'websource'
    env_file: '.env'
    command: 'python -m celery -A pinwins beat --pidfile= -l debug'
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web

  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: 'mdillon/postgis'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/'

  redis:
    container_name: 'redis'
    image: 'redis:3.2.0'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redisdata:/data'

volumes:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
  cachedata:
  mediadata:
  staticdata:
  letsencrypt_certs:
  letsencrypt_www:
```

and Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk add \
  --no-cache \
  --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
  --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
  gdal gdal-dev

# Pillow dependencies
RUN apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev py-pip python-dev build-base

ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
            gcc \
            make \
            libc-dev \
            musl-dev \
            linux-headers \
            pcre-dev \
            postgresql-dev \
    && pyvenv /venv \
    && /venv/bin/pip install -U pip \
    && LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib /bin/sh -c "/venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt" \
    && runDeps="$( \
            scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /venv \
                    | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
                    | sort -u \
                    | xargs -r apk info --installed \
                    | sort -u \
    )" \
    && apk add --virtual .python-rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps

RUN apk add  --no-cache ffmpeg

RUN mkdir /code/
WORKDIR /code/
ADD . /code/

CMD source /venv/bin/activate

EXPOSE 8000
```

I tried to access to pgdata volume but I am not sure where to search for the data, if there is any yet. Do you have any clues why this could had happened? I could manage data loss, but I want to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: I recommend you to see the logs of your Cloud service, to see if somebody reset to a snapshot or so

Comment: There was no snapshot.

Comment: Do you have a cronjob to cleanup docker periodically, like running `docker system prune` or did anyone run it on your system, or do you run them on reboot of the server? Are this droplets based on CoreOS?